# what is the best equivalent of PlotMarkers in ListPlot in Plot command?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have to plot 7 function in a single plot, a toy example may be

```
Plot[Table[x^i, {i, 7}], {x, 0, 5}]
```

This gives me a plot including 7 blue lines, but I want to plot them so that every single curve can be distinguishable. There is `PlotMarkers` option for `ListPlot` which does this in a best way, I want such a equivalent here. Since I guess you suggest the following solutions I write my reason for not using them:

- Using colors: I want to print my plots in black and white
- Using Plot style: there are limited plot styles for for using: solid, dashed,dotted,dott-dashed which are not enough for showing 7 functions for example.
- Calculating points using `Table` and then plotting them by `ListPlot`: The distribution of points of my functions are not suitable for doing this and the overall shape of function isn't identified clearly.
- Using Thickness: Since there are many functions, thickness of curves are not distinguishable.

Any idea?

Comment: how about `Plot[Evaluate@Table[x^i, {i, 7}], {x, 0, 5},  PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",PlotLegends->"Expressions"]`?

Comment: Why not use `ListLinePlot` and use `PlotMarkers` of your choice?

Comment: Use the @kglr answer above with `ScalingFunctions` to reduce plot congestion: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[x^i, {i, 7}], {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"]
 , ScalingFunctions -> {None, "Log"}]`

Comment: @kglr Great job! Please write it as an answer

Comment: Have you considered using [`Callout`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Callout.html) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[x^i, {i, 7}], {x, 0, 5},  
   PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Or to order the legends more like the plot: `Plot[Evaluate@Table[x^i, {i, 7}], {x, 0, 5}, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", PlotLegends -> LineLegend["Expressions", LegendLayout -> "ReversedColumn"], Frame -> True]`